# "after all I have seen" vs "after I have seen all"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> 1. After all I have seen, I know but one thing.
> 2. After I have seen all, I know but one thing.

For me, these two sentences mean the same thing. Could there be any difference?

Comment: They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: They're both in a literary register, but 'After I have seen all' takes it into the restricted section. // But the essence is that 'I have seen everything' is very different in meaning from ' ... everything I have seen'.  The first makes a very hyperbolic claim (one hopes using literary licence intentionally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not mean the same thing.

> After all I have seen, I know but one thing.

means I have seen some things, and after I have seen everything that I have seen I know but one thing.

> After I have seen all, I know but one thing.

means that I have seen *everything*, and after  that I know but one thing.